# Cookies not being saved

Tags: cookies, setcookie, asp.net-web-api2

I have two subdomains, local-api.domain.com and local-web.domain.com

local-web.domain.com has a page (local-web.domain.com/test/authtest) that calls out via AJAX to a login service (local-api.domain.com/authentication/login) on local-api.domain.com. The login checks the user's posted credentials, and if they're valid then logs the user in via ASP.Net forms auth. Here is a sample raw response that comes back from the service:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Set-Cookie: token=dsaaflkdaflkxEfrLEUH2Bsfdsjfdksfjdsklfj; expires=Sat, 11 Jan 2014 00:16:04 GMT; domain=.domain.com; path=/; httponly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://local-web.domain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=E18F1521FFF70FDFD60444F6EA791D28DDF1010F907D35DD13CDA7E2698CE9DCFB50A25853A5BCFEA0E21820A0760D8412D517548F59344EDDA052DD6D7BD7DDB1D47D011F2EFE3B58B6B2690B370D54C560FC6FA3B0990190E0CB8A8B4CC80BEA925CA928256C78C502E74444566785C95EDC399777B3CB0D2AAFFD219B3ED5; domain=.domain.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Visitor=acfbc21b-6259-4000-809d-7dbc72db8309; domain=.domain.com; expires=Sat, 10-Jan-2015 00:16:04 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Visit=78406825-adf1-4224-af57-0350136a5fc6; domain=.domain.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Culture=en; domain=.domain.com; expires=Sat, 10-Jan-2015 00:16:04 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Fri, 10 Jan 2014 00:16:04 GMT
Content-Length: 122

{"token":"dsaaflkdaflkxEfrLEUH2Bsfdsjfdksfjdsklfj","firstName":"Steve","lastName":"Smith"}
```

However, when I reload the page; I find that the cookie that was set in the response is not there. Further investigation with Chrome Developer Tools finds that the cookie doesn't even get saved after the login response; even though there is a Set-Cookie header.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Going by similar questions on the site and their responses; I believe I have everything set up properly for the cookie to be saved and resent across my subdomains. Been Googling for last hour but haven't found anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As reproduced on Charles Proxy application,

Replacing `httponly` with `HttpOnly` on the conflict cookie did work fine.

I think that's the issue.